# Possible Rule of thumb for sums of variances?

Tags: probability, variance

For questions dealing with insurance problems, I will often run into questions that involve finding aggregate variance. In a certain problem, I'm told that there are 50 policies, and various different amounts of claims with their own various probabilities for said claims. Once I've found the expected claim amount per 1 policy, the solution says that I should simply multiply the variance I've found by 50. Why is this the case, and not that if $S=50X$ then $Var[S]=Var[50X]=50^2Var[X]$?

Comment: It is true that $\operatorname{Var}(50 X)=50^2\operatorname{Var}(X)$

Comment: That is what I thought too, but for this problem and many others like it, I have seen that when there is a $\sigma^2$/unit, the variance of the sum ends up being just the sum of the variances. What conditions might cause this to be true?

Comment: It is also true that the variance is additive for uncorrelated random variables. All independent r.v.s are uncorrelated

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by 50 the variance of one variabile or summing the same variance of 50 variabiles is not the same thing.

$V[50X]=50^2V[X]$

But if $X_i \stackrel{d}=X_j$

(All the random variabiles have the same distribution and thus also the same variance, say $V[X]$)

$V[X_1+X_2+...+X_{50}]=50V[X]$

This, IF THE RV'S ARE UNCORRELATED. Otherwise you must sum all the covariances.

$$V[\sum_i X_i]=\sum_i \sum_j Cov(X_i,X_j)$$

These results are very easy to be proved and you can find the proofs in any elementary statistic textbook

Answer (score 0):

The sum of independent r.v.'s is not $50$ times one of them. So the variance properties are that if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent (or pairwise uncorrelated) then
$$
\text{Var}(X_1+\ldots+X_n)=\text{Var}(X_1)+\ldots+\text{Var}(X_n).
$$
So for $50$ identically distributed and *independent* summands it will be $50\text{Var}(X_1)$.

Comment: Thank you, butI guess I'm still having some difficulty with when to apply the sum vs. the product, but here is what I think I'm understanding:  If I have 50 IID policies $X_1,X_2, X_3....X_50$, with  each as their own data point,  with an established, identical,  variance of payout given as constant Q, then the variance of these 50 policies,  taken together would be the sum, or 50Q? On the other hand, if I had 50 IID policies, with a given payout of 100 per per policy would the variance on the payout then be $100^2 \cdot 50\cdot Q$?

Comment: @PortMadeleineCrumpet Yes, if you have 50 IID policies with variance of payout $Q$, then the variance of these 50 policies would be the sum of 50 $Q$, that is $50Q$. If you have 50 policies with constant payout 100 per policy, then the variance would be zero since constant random variable has zero variance. If you multiply every of the 50 IID payouts with constant variance $Q$ by 100, then the variance of the total payout would be $100^2\cdot 50\cdot Q$.